# New-PnPSite - But create a hub site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Is their a way to use New-PnPSite to create a hub site?

Register-SPOHubSite or a PNP version of this command?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I have used below command to create a hub site:

```
Register-PnPHubSite
```